# Break when value change inside php loop

Tags: php

I want to make a loop php to extract words from json file.
Everything is ok but i just need to break line when the x value change.

```
$a = $cell["_x"];
foreach ($cell as $key => $value ){
    if ($a = $a+1) {
        echo "<br>";
    else {
        echo $value3["_solution"] ;              
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
"cell": [
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "1",
        "_solution": "F",
        "_number": "1"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "2",
        "_solution": "A",
        "_number": "15"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "3",
        "_solution": "T",
        "_number": "18"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "4",
        "_solution": "L",
        "_number": "21"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "5",
        "_solution": "I",
        "_number": "24"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "6",
        "_solution": "P",
        "_number": "30"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "7",
        "_type": "block"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "8",
        "_solution": "S",
        "_number": "37"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "9",
        "_solution": "H",
        "_number": "42"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "10",
        "_solution": "O",
        "_number": "45"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "11",
        "_solution": "P",
        "_number": "51"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "12",
        "_type": "block"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "13",
        "_solution": "O",
        "_number": "59"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "14",
        "_solution": "T",
        "_number": "63"
    },
    {
        "_x": "1",
        "_y": "15",
        "_solution": "C",
        "_number": "66"
    },
    {
        "_x": "2",
        "_y": "1",
        "_solution": "O",
        "_number": "2"
    },
    {
        "_x": "2",
        "_y": "2",
        "_solution": "F"
    },
    {
        "_x": "2",
        "_y": "3",
        "_solution": "F"
    },
    {
        "_x": "2",
        "_y": "4",
        "_solution": "I"
    },
    {
        "_x": "2",
        "_y": "5",
        "_solution": "C"
    },
    {
        "_x": "2",
        "_y": "6",
        "_solution": "E"
    },
```

I also tried while loop, for loop etc, but no function can make break when the x value change from `1` to `2` .

Ex : all functions will print OTCOFFICE or it's two words

```
OTC 
OFFICE
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is incorrect. `=` is not the same as `==`.

Comment: `}` is also missing in your `else` statement

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, i tried all statement and sorry for }, i have a result but words are the words are glued. i want to make a break just one time when the X value change

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JSON and you have parse errors, but ignoring that; assuming that you've decoded it with:

```
$cell = json_decode($j, true)["cell"];
```

You just need to check that the current `_x` is not equal to the previous one and then set it.

```
$a = reset($cell)["_x"];

foreach ($cell as $key => $value ) {
    if($value["_x"] != $a) {
        $a = $value["_x"];
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo $value["_solution"] ?? "none";  // set to whatever
}
```

`_solution` doesn't exits in some arrays, so I echoed `none` or replace with `<br>` or whatever.

Comment: You are a genius, work like a charm. My code is not complete i just cut some crossword words. The original file is XML i convert it to json and there is no underscore with json.

Comment: You changed the code, the first one work very well :if ($value3["x"] != $a ) {
                $a = $value3["x"];
               echo "<br>";
                        }
        echo $value3["solution"] ; 
  
      }